# Onlyoffice integrate into nextcloud. Error while downloading the document file to be converted

Tags: nextcloud, onlyoffice

I had already looked around, but this couldn't solve my problem. I installed onlyoffice documents on another server.now i would like to use the addon in nextcloud. When I enter the serverip in Nextcloud, I get the following error:
Error while downloading the document file to be converted

in the nextcloud config i also have " 'onlyoffice' =>array (
  verify_peer_off' => TRUE, 
  ) 
" added.

Called up via healthcheck I get a positive result.

here is an excerpt from the log of the converter:

```
[2019-08-29T16:29:49.962] [WARN] nodeJS - worker 11687 started.
[2019-08-29T16:29:49.963] [WARN] nodeJS - update cluster with 1 workers
[2019-08-29T16:40:12.293] [ERROR] nodeJS - error downloadFile:url=https://next.mydomain.xx/apps/onlyoffice/empty?doc=eyJ0eXAiOiJxyzv4oPYyTYdvdZNgMz$
```

`Error: Parse Error
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:454:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)`
`at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)`
`at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:601:20)`

i am very happy to suggest solutions

Comment: You are missing a single quote in front of verify_peer_off

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that next.mydomain.xx cannot be validated by DocumentServer.

You can disable certificate verification in DS config
`/etc/onlyoffice/documentserver/default.json` by setting `rejectUnauthorized` to `false`. After that, you need to restart DS services: `supervisorctl restart al`l
If that doesn't help, specify the version, OS and installation type of the DocumentServer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. but it still doesn't work. I receive this error message:
rror when trying to connect (Error occurred in the document service: Error while downloading the document file to be converted.)

For testing reasons I also deactivated the firewall. still no improvement. 

Nextcloud Server is Debian

Document Server: I used this installation guide:
https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/de/server/linux/document/linux-installation.aspx

Except for "Additional information" I did everything according to the instructions.

Comment: System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I have read iwo that the certificate of the document server on which the Nextcloud is installed must also be installed. is this correct? if yes, do you have any instructions?

If you need more logs, I will be happy to send them to you.

Comment: I have installed the OO document server via Docker and do not have a onlyoffice folder under /etc. Where is the default.json file located for docker installations?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it resolved the problem:

```
  - JWT_ENABLED=true
  - JWT_SECRET=secret
  - JWT_HEADER=AuthorizationJwt
  - JWT_IN_BODY=true
  - USE_UNAUTHORIZED_STORAGE=true
```

and in Nextcloud's config.php:

```
  array (
    "jwt_secret" => "secret",
    "jwt_header" => "AuthorizationJwt"
  ),
```

Ref:

1. https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/onlyoffice-nextcloud/issues/601
2. https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/Docker-DocumentServer#available-configuration-parameters

Comment: It is no longer necessary to edit the NC config.php as the settings are available on the ONLYOFFICE app page https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/onlyoffice-nextcloud/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#added